# Using jsbi in a typescript project with strict mode

Tags: javascript, typescript, bigint

I'm working on a typescript library that is using native `BigInt`s. It works great in chrome, but not in Safari. So I came across the `jsbi` "polyfill" that takes care of this.

But for some reason, I can't import the library correctly.

I first tried to import it like this:

`import JSBI from 'jsbi'`

The types are correct, but at runtime `JSBI` is undefined and I cannot call any methods on it. (eg. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'subtract' of undefined`)

So I tried doing:

`import * as JSBI from 'jsbi'`

But then it wouldn't even compile, I get various errors like `Cannot use namespace 'JSBI' as a type.`. I also tried to access the methods like this `JSBI.JSBI.subtract`, but then I get the error `Property 'JSBI' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/project/node_modules/jsbi/jsbi")'.`

The only way I got it working was by using the following import:

`import * as JSBI from 'jsbi/dist/jsbi-umd.js'`

This actually worked. JSBI is defined at runtime and I can access its methods. However, it only works when strict mode is disabled. When I enable it, i get the error

```
error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'jsbi/dist/jsbi-umd.js'.
 '/project/node_modules/jsbi/dist/jsbi-umd.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/jsbi` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'jsbi/dist/jsbi-umd.js';`
```

I event tried to declare my own .d.ts module as a temporary fix, but it didn't work work either.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Comment: I think we used another library in the end.

Comment: I think I found a way around this (by using `require` instead of `import` or something along that line) but it still had some annoying issues and in the end I've settled with the native bigint.

Comment: Have you guy solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

JSBI has been migrated to Typescript and includes a .d.ts file. This problem should be resolved. https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/jsbi/pull/67

Comment: I'm setting the same issues as the original poster.  The only way I could get it to compile was to use the "import * as JSBI from 'jsbi/dist/jsbi-umd.js'" workaround.

Comment: In my use case, 'import JSBI from "jsbi";' is working fine. https://github.com/Leslie-Wong-H/jsbi-calculator/blob/main/src/jsbi-calculator.ts#L9